# How can I evaluate the upper or lower bound for a function of random variables?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, bounds

Let $\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2$, and $\Gamma_3$ be random variables defined as:

\begin{align}
\Gamma_1 &= \frac{XY}{X + Y + 1}  \\[10pt]
\Gamma_2 &= \frac{XY}{aX + bY + c}  \\[10pt]
\Gamma_3 &= \frac{XY}{aX + bY + cZ + d}
\end{align}

where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ follow exponential distributions with different parameters, and $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are positive constants.

Even though I have the exact CDF for $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$, it becomes mathematically intractable to derive the exact CDF of $\Gamma_3$. So I was thinking of trying to find either the upper bound or the lower bound.

**Question:** How can I evaluate the bounds for $\Gamma_3$?

Should I try to evaluate the lower bound or the upper bound?